# Who is the baby Lucca picked up?

Tags: chrono-trigger

in the Ending Cinematic of *Chrono Trigger* (i'm playing the DS Version). at the very end Lucca sees something glowing and finds a baby with a pendent before picking it up and taking it with her

[image: Lucca seeing the glow][image: Lucca seeing the baby][image: the baby and the pendent][image: Lucca leaving with the baby]

I doubt it's Magus because while we see all the character but him (and Zero if you don't count Lucca's re-creation) Magus had pale blue hair, not to mention he was older than the baby when Zeal was initially destroyed (when he and the Gurus were scattered across time and he was found by Ozzie)

So who is this baby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Kid, the heroine of Chrono Cross.

Sources:

- [Lucca's wikia page](https://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/Lucca)
- [Kid's wikia page](https://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/Kid)

*Both of them also contain the exact same image you have linked*